# Display dynamically generated images as soon as image received via AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, image, dom-events

What I am trying to do is load images that I am dynamically generating one after another before page fully loaded. Here is what I am doing. I am making ASYNC requests to server via `createXMLHttpRequest`. On a server side I am creating new image (chart image) and returning image attributes in JSON format.

Here is snippet of html code:

```
<!-- first image -->  
<div id="image3Obj">
     <div id="image3"><img src="img/loader32.gif"></div>
</div>

<!--second image -->
<div id="image2Obj">
     <div id="image2"><img src="img/loader32.gif"></div>
</div>

<!-- third image-->
<div id="image1Obj">
    <div id="image1"><img src="img/loader32.gif"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" defer>load_components();</script>
```

Snippet of Javascript code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="Javascript" src="js_lib/ajaxCaller.js"></SCRIPT>

<script type="text/javascript">

function load_components() {
     createUrlStr('url1');
     createUrlStr('url2');
     createUrlStr('url3');
}


function createUrlStr(url)
     // make async request to server and generating brand new image, then returning   image div name, source, width and height back in json format
    ajaxCaller.getPlainText(url_str, loadImage);
}

function loadImage() {
    var jsonObj = eval('(' + xReq.responseText + ')');
    if (jsonObj.imgDiv != undefined && jsonObj.imgSrc != undefined) {
         var newImg = document.createElement("img");
         newImg.src = jsonObj.imgSrc;
         if (jsonObj.imgWidth != undefined && jsonObj.imgHeight != undefined) {
             newImg.width = jsonObj.imgWidth;
             newImg.height = jsonObj.imgHeight;
         }
         document.getElementById(jsonObj.imgDiv).appendChild(newImg);
    }
}

</script>
```

Problem is that images get loaded one after another on html, but only getting displayed   when last image is loaded. Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

My guess, without seeing an actual example, is that because you are running all 3 async requests at the same time it all happens so quickly they appear to happen at the same time when really they may be spaced apart by a few milliseconds.  If you delay your requests like the following example does it appear as desired?

```
function load_components() {
    var x,y,z;

    x = setTimeout(function(){ createUrlStr('url1'); }, 100);
    y = setTimeout(function(){ createUrlStr('url2'); }, 2000);
    z = setTimeout(function(){ createUrlStr('url3'); }, 5000);
}
```

Also keep in mind that while you are generating the image on the server-side and inserting the tag in order, the image data is being downloaded after the fact by the browser not your AJAX request. To see this happening check out the NET tab in Firebug.